# Set as subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Check and prove if the sets below are subspaces:
$$
V = \left\{ (x,y,z) \in R^{3} : x,y = 0 \right\} \\
W = \left\{ (x,2x,3x...nx)  : x \in R \right\} \\
U = \left\{ v \in R^{5} : \text{has two or more null entries }\right\} 
$$
My answers:

For V:
When z coordinate is 0, we'll get $(0,0,0)$, thus:
$$
 \left\{ 0 \right\} \in V
$$
It's closed under addition:
$$
(0,0,a) \in V : a \in R\\
(0,0,b) \in V: b \in R\\
(0,0,a) + (0,0,b) \in V
$$
And it's closed under multiplication:
$$
\beta \cdot (0,0,a) = (0,0,\beta \cdot a) \in V : a,\beta \in R\\
$$
So V is a subspace!

For W:
When x is 0, we'll get $(0,2\cdot0, 3\cdot0,...n\cdot0)$, thus:
$$
 \left\{ 0 \right\} \in V
$$

It's closed under addition:
$$
(x,2x,3x...nx) \in W : x\in R\\
(y,2y,3y...ny) \in W : y\in R\\
(x,2x,3x...nx) + (y,2y,3y...ny) = \\
(x+y,2(x+y),3(x+y)...n(x+y))\in W
$$

And it's closed under multiplication:
$$
\gamma \cdot (x,2x,3x...nx) = \\\
(\gamma x, 2\gamma x, 3\gamma x...n\gamma x) \in W : x,\gamma\in R\\
$$

So W is a subspace!

For U:
Since it can has all entries null:
$$
 \left\{ 0 \right\} \in V
$$

It's not closed under addition:
$$
a = (0,0,1,1,1) \in U\\
b = (1,1,0,0,0) \in U\\
a+b = (1,1,1,1,1) \notin U
$$

So U is not a subspace!

It's everything correct? Is there a better way to prove if a set is a subspace?!

Comment: Your answer is correct. Another way to show $W$ is a subspace is to show that it is the span of some vectors. In this case, $W$ is the span of the vector $(1,2,\dots, n)$. But using definition as you did is good enough.

Comment: For a set like: {$(x,y,z) \in R^{3} : x\cdot y = 0$} Can I assume that it's not a subspace since it's not closed under multiplication?

Comment: It is closed under scalar multiplication, but not closed under addition.